# Reordering CollectionView cells iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios11

I know that iOS 11 brings the new drag and drop functionality to collectionview but I have a completely separate issue using it. So I thought I'd try using the old way which was introduced in IOS 9 ([see this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20170915133601/http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/)). My problem is that on iOS 11, the ending animation when your finger is removed acts weird ONLY when two cells are switched. You can see the problem in this [clip](https://giphy.com/gifs/sKxPLESJuoueA).

I've been trying to figure this out for days, with no luck. It works fine on iOS 10 but not iOS 11. Any help would be appreciated.

Extra info: I'm using a collectionview with a long press gesture to initiate the reorder gesture as seen in the first link. However, the problem still occurs when using a uicollectionviewcontroller

Here's the code for the long press gesture:

```
func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    switch(gesture.state) {

    case .began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case .changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case .ended:
      // this part misbehaves on ios 11 when two cells are swapped
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        )}
    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code snippets to illustrate your problem and make it easier to help you.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem in a horizontal collectionview, but not a vertical. Is yours horizontal?

Comment: That is strange... mine is vertical

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I’m having the exact same problem.

Comment: Update: I was unintentionally making a call to invalidateLayout() after calling endInteractiveMovement(). invalidateLayout() was causing the ugly animation glitch for me. Not calling invalidateLayout() _seems_ to have fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

To begin, you don't need to place `collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()` inside of a `performBatchUpdates` block. But nonetheless, this issue has been an annoyance for me as well. The discrepancy between iOS 10 and 11 with this `endInteractiveMovement` things doesn't make much sense.

For my problem, I am placing a fake snapshot cell above my collectionView, and hiding the content below as I run through gesture state changes and `updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition`. Once the gesture state has `.ended`, I *was* removing the fake cell from the superview, then performing the `endInteractiveMovement`. But now with iOS 11, I was experiencing the same issue as @prolfe in the comments from the previous answer. I was getting this weird flash due to this unforeseen reload of the cell in question.

The solution I ended up going with was to place a delay on my fake cell removal, so that it kind of 'covers up' the flash.

My `pushBackView` method animates the fake cell back to the drop position, then removes the fake cell. I then enact the delay:

```
case .ended:

        fakeCellView?.pushBackView { [weak self] in // 'suppress' cell animation

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .seconds(0.01), execute: {
                self?.fakeCellView?.removeFromSuperview()
            })

            self?.collectionView?.endInteractiveMovement()
        }
```

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: So you're counting on the moved cell's reload to happen within 1/100th of a second, right? I feel like that's not a guaranteed thing. Clever, but not a GREAT solution. I'm still searching for something that can conclusively say the item invalidation and cell reload is done after `endInteractiveMovement()` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do `self.collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()` inside performBatchUpdates block.

Comment: it is necessary for iOS 10 to avoid weird behaviour with letting go of cell during dragging. I expected it to function similarly in iOS 11 but it does not.

Comment: I haven't tried in iOS10, I am working on a new iOS11 project. If it behaves different in both OS's why don't you use: `if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { /* iOS11 code */ } else { /* iOS10 code */ }`. I know it is annoying but there have been some changes in collectionViews..

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too and the worst part is, iOS 11 behaves unexpectedly with and without the call to performBatchUpdates. I haven't been able to check if It's been corrected since the official release of iOS 11.

Comment: I am also having issues with iOS 11 and the `endIntractiveMovement` function. It seems that the CollectionView is reloading the cell that is moved very soon after it's moved (asynchronously). So for me, I'm seeing a flash. And I also am unable to do any other collectionview manipulation after this because of the delayed reload of that cell. `#available` doesn't really apply here because there's not a good alternative in iOS 11 that I've found. 